# how to specify delimiter when uploading csv onto snowflake using snowflake connector & COPY INTO function

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am uploading a csv file onto snowflake using the snowflake python connector. The CSV file needs to have a pipe delimiter. How can I specify this delimiter in the COPY INTO function?

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=os.environ.get("USER_NAME"),
    password=os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
    account=os.environ.get("ACCOUNT"),
    warehouse=os.environ.get("WAREHOUSE"),
    database=os.environ.get("DATABASE"),
    schema=os.environ.get("SCHEMA"),
    role=os.environ.get("ROLE"))
conn.cursor().execute("PUT file://{} @%test)
conn.cursor().execute("COPY INTO test_table")
conn.cursor().close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the parameter `FIELD_DELIMITER = 'character'`

Example in your case:

```
COPY INTO test_table file_format = (type=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|');
```

For more information and some other parameters you can have a look here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html